# Why q is not equal to 1.0?

Tags: c++

I'm a neophyte with c++. I wrote this code but the result for q have to be 1.0, but the code give me, changing the variable's order when I recall function "intercetta", for example -34, 0, 9.75. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float m) {
    return m = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
}
float intercetta(float m, float x1, float y1, float q) {
    return q = y1 - m * x1;
}
int main() {
    float x1, x2, y1, y2, m=0, q=0;
    x1 = 3.5;
    x2 = 6.5;
    y1 = 9.75;
    y2 = 17.25;
    cout << "m= " << coefficienteAngolare(x1, x2, y1, y2, m) << endl;
    cout << "q= " << intercetta(x1, y1, m, q) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `return m = …` do you expect this to change the value of `m` in `main()`?

Comment: How can I do to let main read the value of m?

Comment: I have to pass m by value? How can I do it?

Comment: Is it intentional that you call `intercetta(x1, y1, m, q)` instead of `intercetta(m, x1, y1, q)`? Do you understand what the concept of pass-by-value versus pass-by-reference means?

Comment: As I said, i'm a neophyte

Comment: I don't know the math behind your code but your function intercetta expects m, x1, y1, q variables in order. When calling the function you send x1, y1, m, q in this order. You should write variables in exact same order, as declared.

Comment: Even if i write **'intercetta(m, x1, x2, q)'**, m is not equal to 1.0.By math It must be 1.0

Comment: Why do you think m should be 1.0? If you want to change the value of the variable inside the function , you should pass by reference your variable. Which is done by adding & before name.     

cout << "q= " << intercetta(x1, y1, &m, q) << endl;

Comment: Sorry, q must be 1.0

Comment: q=y1-m*x1, with y1=9.75, m=2.5, x1=3.5. Do the math and the result is 1.0

Comment: You are passing in the parameters m=3.5 (from x1 argument), x1=9.75 (from y1 argument), and y1=2.5 (from m argument).  If you do the math, it must be `-31.625`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
float coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float m) {
    return m = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
}
```

has parameters passed by value. It means that it receives copies of the parameters you give. Whatever you do inside the function, cannot alter the parameters passed to it in `main()`.

If you *really* want to modify `m`, you have to pass it by reference

```
float coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float& m) {
    return m = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
}
```

But then, if you modify `m`, why do you need to return it?
Most probably you either want to *not* return anything and just store the result in m

```
void coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float& m) {
    m = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
}

//....
// in main()
coefficienteAngolare(x1, x2, y1, y2, m);
cout << "m= " << m << endl;
```

Or you want to return the resulting value, without passing a variable to store it.

```
float coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
    return ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
}

//....
// in main()
m = coefficienteAngolare(x1, x2, y1, y2);
cout << "m= " << m << endl;
```

Along the same line you have to modify `intercetta`.
Please notice that the order of the parameters is relevant. The compiler cannot *guess* that the `q` variable in `main()` should be the same as the `q` variable in `intercetta`, they belong to different scopes.

Comment: `std::cout << "m= " << m << '\n';`

Comment: Ok now it works: (I don't know how to put code in comments). float coefficienteAngolare(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, float &m). THX

Comment: @padrepio1000 Comments are not suitable to enter long pieces of code. To enter code, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291215/8769985). If this or another answer suits your question, you can decide to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). There is not obligation to that.

Comment: `example code eddea`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `m` (and `q`) in your `main` function are different variables than the variables in your other functions. The assignment you have after your `return` statement assigns a value to a variable which has its [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) limited to the respective function's [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

If you want to pass-by-reference, you can do this by declaring the argument as a reference:

```
float intercetta(float m, float x1, float y1, float& q) {
                                                // ^-------- reference
```

Comment: It doesn't work, q = 9.75. But it must be 1.0

Comment: @padrepio1000 Did you make both `m` and `q` reference arguments **and** did you make sure to pass the arguments to `intercetta` in the correct order?

Comment: As declared, yes